# Destroy/disable and use native form select instead of Selecitze.js only on mobile/tablet

Tags: forms, select, native, selectize.js

Does anyone know a way to destroy/disable Selectize.js on mobile/tablet so that user gets native select layout? Something like Chosen has by default...

Cheers!